# Getting started with SOAP for Delphi in Win32

Tags: delphi, soap, remobjects

I have a server process built in Delphi/C++Builder with RemObjects SDK which claims to support SOAP requests.

What's the quickest and easiest way of testing out the SOAP support? I'd prefer not to have to learn a new language/install a new IDE/spend more than a day...

To clarify this, I'm already connecting to the server happily using the RO native protocol, and have SOAP enabled, but I want to test how systems NOT based on the RO SDK can use it. Using RO SOAP for both client and server doesn't accomplish this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried it with RemObjects, but if the server already supports SOAP, I can't think of an easier way to test it than to simply consume the web service using Delphi and call each of the methods.  It's surprisingly straight forward.

- Create a new application.
- In File|New|Other|WebServices choose WSDL Importer.
- Enter the server's WSDL page.  A wrapper unit is created for you with all of the web service methods and any additional classes/enumerations the web service uses.

Just above the Implementation section, you will see a method to return an instance of your web service class:

```
function GetMyServerSoap(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): MyServerSoap;
```

Instantiate it with the defaults and start calling methods.

If you want/need to see the XML being sent and received, supply your own HTTPRIO component and use the OnBeforeExecute and OnExecute events.

Comment: Thanks, Bruce. That was incredibly painless once I realised that WSDL importer was only available once the application had been created!

Answer (score 4):

Try [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) - it is a free SOAP toolkit which makes it easy to analyze and test SOAP services.

> soapUI is a free and open source
>   desktop application for
>
> ```
> * inspecting Web Services
> * invoking Web Services
> * developing Web Services
> * Web Services Simulation and Mocking
> * Functional, Load and Compliance testing of Web Services
> ```
>
> It is mainly aimed at developers and
>   testers providing or consuming WSDL or
>   REST based Web Services (Java, .net,
>   etc). Functional and Load Testing can
>   be done both interactively in soapUI
>   or within an automated build or
>   integration process using the soapUI
>   command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the tutorials on their web site. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just publish your service with TROSOAPMessage, like others message formats like TROBinMessage, that it.

Check the RO website tutorials about the subject